# Unable to load css from node modules package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack

I am trying to import css from node modules package.

`import "packageName/dist/index.bundle.css";`

I get the error "currently no loaders are configured to process this file."

I am using MiniCssExtractPlugin and have the following web pack configurations to load css -

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = new _MiniCssExtractPlugin({
  filename: "[name].bundle.css",
  chunkFilename: "[id].css",
});

AND 

test: /\.css$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
      options: {
        publicPath: __dirname + "/../../public/css/",
      },
    },
    {
      loader: "css-loader",
      options: {
        importLoaders: 1,
        modules: {
          localIdentName: "[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]",
        },
      },
    },
    {
      loader: "postcss-loader",
      options: {
        config: {
          path: __dirname + "/postcss.config.js",
        },
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

Comment: You know you have `exclude: /node_modules/,` in there, right?

Comment: Yeah I do, but how do I include css of that specific package without including other node module css

Comment: that's not how webpack works: it bundles everything that you import, so in a normal webpack config there shouldn't be any reason to exclude dirs: if you don't `require` them in your code, webpack has no reason to even look at them.

Comment: Got it but how can I avoid hashing the external node module css? It changes the localIdentName

Comment: Why would you avoid it? It gets generated once and then as long as it doesn't change, webpack will just generate "the exact same file" each time. If it didn't, browsers wouldn't be able to cache anything.